# Issue with freezing display with PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt

I recently made a post describing a problem I am having where my display for a QT GUI I am making will freeze. It is still running in the background at this time, but the UI elements will no longer update until I do one of these things: minimize/maximize/move window, change an element value, click a push button.

In my last post, I did not post enough code, I am starting to think it may have something to do with my implementation of QThread coupled with an multiprocessing process.

This app has a grid of QPushButtons that, after a user chooses a start and end position, a colored square on the grid will follow the path from start to finish. This is done by coloring the next square in the path red while coloring the previous square gray to simulate walking down the path.

I have a state machine QThread MP process running that will ultimately call the function to change the button color, so the color changing function is in the context of the state machine thread/process. Also you can tell me if having the MP and QThread is redundant.

Here is relevant code; I cut down 90% of it to just pull out the important bits while changing some things to make it simpler to read, it may not be syntax perfect:

Ui.py

```
    def __init__(self, app):
        super(Ui, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('ui/digitalfluidapp.ui', self)

        # Create grid & button queue
        queue = mp.Queue()
        self.grid_buttons = {}
        self.init_grid_ui(queue)
        grid = Grid(self.grid_buttons)

        # Create and start state machine object
        self.sm = StateMachine(queue, self.grid_buttons, grid)
        self.sm_proc = mp.Process(target = self.sm.start())
        self.sm_proc.start()
```

grid.py

```
class Grid:
    def __init__(self, grid_buttons):
        self.grid = [[0]*NUM_COLS for _ in range(NUM_ROWS)]
        self.init_skip_spaces()
        self.grid_buttons = grid_buttons

    def next_move(self, pos, new_pos):
        if (sim == True):
            self.grid_buttons[pos].change_color('gray')
            self.grid_buttons[new_pos].change_color('red')
```

statemachine.py

```
class StateMachine(QThread):
    def __init__(self, queue, buttons, grid):
        super().__init__()
        self.queue = queue
        self.buttons = buttons
        self.grid = grid
        self._run_flag = true

    def run(self):
        while self._run_flag:
            self.perform_execute_step()

    def perform_execute_step(self):
        self.grid.next_move(pos, new_pos)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `mp.Process(target = self.sm.start)` (without parentheses)?

Comment: As with all your other questions on this topic, nobody is going to be able to help you much unless you provide a proper [mre]. But please note that Qt *does not support gui operations of any kind outside the main thread*. So if `next_move` or `change_color` attempt to *directly* update the gui components in any way, that is guaranteed to fail sooner or later. To avoid such problems, the usual solution is to use custom signals to communicate between the worker and main threads.

Comment: @ekhumoro That was it! I did not realize the main worker thread needed to be the one to change GUI components. What I did was, I changed my Grid class to a QObject and added a signal/slot that let's the main worker thread change colors. No more freezes of the GUI. Thank you for helping!